# What happened to SVDPress?

Tags: dnd-4e, publishing, fourthcore

I used to read SVDPress's blog about fourthcore and their updates but the last time I went to their site it simply was a download page for the three fourthcore modules they created. I've archived them personally, and I hope it stays up, but does anyone know what happened to SVDPress? Are they still working on fourthcore and/or do they still exist in any form or is the site now just a download page and monument to their legacy?

I've been able to find the site in the older format on the WayBackWhenMachine to get to things such as their excellent article "[What is Fourthcore](http://web.archive.org/web/20120531143922/http://slamdancr.com/wp/fourthcore/)" to share with friends, but beyond that I cannont find anything else.

Upon revisiting the site, the domain is completely gone at this point. Anyone interested in the SVDPress's Fourthcore Modules can download them from my [Microsoft OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=723A28155692C47F!649&authkey=!ACSJ6EEwZmyU5pk&ithint=folder,).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We're quiet, publicly, at the moment.

However, we're hard at work on 3 full-length books, a tournament adventure for Kobold Press, and two stand-alone roleplaying games, to be released over the next 2-4 years.