# What's a good adventure to begin a level 1 D&D 4E campaign?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures

I'm looking for a good adventure to start a new campaign from levels 1 to 30 with some friends!

Our campaign is gonna be based on the .hack// games, where people get trapped inside an online game, so ANY ADVENTURE WORKS.

However I'd like something that is easy to introduce them to combat and traps and that doesn't requires many sessions to run. I have Keep on the Shadowfell but find it too much time consuming; looking for something of similar length to the adventure found on DM's Handbook (I've used it before with my players).

I have a party size of 4 players that includes:

- Fighter
- Rogue
- Psion
- Cleric

I would like something fun that won't last more than a single session (we usually spend about 3 hours a day playing).

Comment: Right now almost any short-ish adventure would qualify for your requirements. Take a look at [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19176/4398)--which probably isn't a duplicate because it's asking for a single encounter, despite most answers giving entire adventures--for some ideas about the kind of additional details you might want to add to your request so we can give more useful answers than just guessing. Party size, session length, whether you want it to be fun or scary...

Comment: What level of system mastery do your players have? Is fourthcore right for you?

Comment: I have 2 4E experienced players, one 3.5 veteran and a new comer to roleplaying, all of them quite young (no older than 18, save for the veteran). I have mastered Savage Worlds and Anima: Beyond Fantasy before, also 4E was my first role playing system and maybe my favorite one, tho I still have issues designing dungeons for myself.

Answer (score 3):

Given the game-like setting and the hard 3 hour timelimit, I'd recommend bookending the campaign's chapters with sessions from [Fourthcore](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/8282/760) adventures (archived [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/24967/what-happened-to-svdpress)). You could do far worse than run encounters from [the fourthcore hardcore team deathmatch](http://www.fourthcoreteamdeathmatch.com/) as a campaign.

I've run this as an opener before with two tweaks: first the enemy is not death, but time. When the party TPKs, the dungeon resets. The party has *exactly* three hours to complete the dungeon.

The trick is to introduce this as the chapter opener and closer. "Tonight will be a test of your skills. You will almost certainly fail. As you grow more powerful, you may choose to return to try again." Thus, the adventure arc will open and close with these modules (neatly framed at multiple levels). Beyond that, use chaos scar vignettes from DDI for intirm *much less deadly* encounters and adventures.

Answer (score -1):

If you stick to 4th edition rules, it is pretty much impossible to get from level 1 to level 2 in 3 hours. In 4E you need about 10 encounters of standard difficulty to gain a level, and that would more easily be two or three sessions than one.

Having said that, HS1 The Slaying Stone is an official 4E adventure for 1st level characters, and it is shorter and more interesting than Keep on the Shadowfell. Then at level 2 I'd recommend Reavers of Harkenwold from the Dungeon Master's Kit.